Optimizing Lat/Lon Extraction from Astropy's GeocentricTrueEcliptic SkyCoord
I am facing a challenge that should be straightforward but has proven to be quite complex with the Astropy library. Specifically, I need to frequently compute the longitude and latitude from a SkyCoord object that has been transformed to the GeocentricTrueEcliptic frame. Here is the relevant section of my code:
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, GeocentricTrueEcliptic, ICRS
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.time import Time

coo_icrs = SkyCoord(150*u.deg, 19*u.deg, frame=ICRS(), obstime=Time(2460791., format="jd"))
coo = coo_icrs.geocentrictrueecliptic
some_function(coo.lon, coo.lat)

Accessing coo.lon and coo.lat proves to be time-consuming due to unnecessary computations that don’t align with my use case. The issue is exacerbated as this computation needs to be repeated millions of times during each testing phase of my module, significantly impacting performance.
Upon investigation, I found that coo.lon and coo.lat may be slow because SkyCoord performs a transformation to spherical coordinates. I discovered a much faster approach by directly accessing internal attributes (coo_icrs._sky_coord_frame._data):
%timeit coo_icrs._sky_coord_frame._data._lon
%timeit coo_icrs.ra
# 46.1 ns ± 0.203 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
# 6.21 µs ± 69.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

However, this shortcut doesn’t apply to coo since its coordinates are only available in XYZ Cartesian format:
coo._sky_coord_frame._data
# <CartesianRepresentation (x, y, z) [dimensionless]
#    (-0.83586289, 0.53450713, 0.12504145)>

Extracting values directly (._x.value, ._y.value, and ._z.value) and converting them manually to longitude and latitude is still faster than using coo.lon and coo.lat, but this manual conversion is also computationally intensive.
I am searching for a method to more efficiently retrieve longitude and latitude values from a SkyCoord object in the GeocentricTrueEcliptic frame, avoiding the extra computational overhead. Is there a faster, more direct way to obtain these values?

The following answer is a concise excerpt from my blog Enhancing Performance of Latitude and Longitude Extraction from Astropy's GeocentricTrueEcliptic Frame.
The three functions presented below calculate latitude and longitude, as radians, using x, y, and z from the astropy.coordinates.sky_coordinate.SkyCoord object.
There is a numpy option, and two numba enhanced versions-one using the JIT and the other adding parallel processing.

@jit: Compiling Python code with @jit
cache: Cache the compiled function on disk
parallel: Automatic parallelization

Results Summary
This analysis demonstrates improved performance when using Numba-enhanced functions for calculating spherical coordinates.

Detailed Time Measurements:

Direct access to .lat and .lon properties took about 17.73 µs (8.89 µs for .lat and 8.84 µs for .lon).
Retrieving x, y, and z values directly (467 ns, 450 ns, and 458 ns respectively) summed to approximately 1.375 µs.
The cartesian_to_spherical_numba computation took 267 ns.


Combining the time for direct value retrieval and computation:

Total time for Numba-enhanced computation (cartesian_to_spherical_numba): 1.375 µs (value retrieval) + 267 ns = 1.642 µs.
This is about 10.8 times faster than the direct access method for .lat and .lon (17.73 µs / 1.642 µs ≈ 10.8).



These results demonstrate the gains achieved by using JIT compilation. This can be further enhanced by parallelization, if arrays of coordinates are used.
Relevant Imports
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord, GeocentricTrueEcliptic, ICRS, Angle
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.time import Time
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange
from typing import Tuple, Union


Python: 3.12.0
Astropy Version: 6.0.1
Numba Version: 0.59.1
Numpy Version: 1.26.4

Initial Code
# International Celestial Reference System coordinates
coo_icrs = SkyCoord(150*u.deg, 19*u.deg, frame=ICRS(), obstime=Time(2460791., format="jd"))
# Ecliptic coordinates
ecliptic_coords = coo_icrs.transform_to(GeocentricTrueEcliptic)

print(ecliptic_coords.lat, ecliptic_coords.lon)

[6d21m12.19206726s] [145d28m31.99626325s]
timeit for various functions
Accessing ._sky_coord_frame._data.x.value is significantly faster, taking only 467 ns, compared to 6.14 µs when using .cartesian.x.value. However, the use of a single underscore (_) prefix in the names of attributes or methods signifies they are intended to be "protected" or for internal use. See this question, Private Variables, and Public vs Non-Public Members for additional details.
%timeit ecliptic_coords.lat
8.89 µs ± 132 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit ecliptic_coords.lon
8.84 µs ± 413 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit ecliptic_coords._sky_coord_frame._data
76.5 ns ± 0.507 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
%timeit ecliptic_coords._sky_coord_frame._data.xyz.value
15.8 µs ± 351 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
%timeit ecliptic_coords._sky_coord_frame._data.x.value
467 ns ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
%timeit ecliptic_coords._sky_coord_frame._data.y.value
450 ns ± 3.89 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
%timeit ecliptic_coords._sky_coord_frame._data.z.value
458 ns ± 6.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
%timeit ecliptic_coords.cartesian.xyz.value
25.1 µs ± 409 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
%timeit ecliptic_coords.cartesian.x.value
6.14 µs ± 215 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

Code to Calculate Longitude and Latitude
def cartesian_to_spherical_numpy(
    x: Union[np.ndarray, np.float64],
    y: Union[np.ndarray, np.float64],
    z: Union[np.ndarray, np.float64]
    ) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """
    Convert Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates using NumPy.

    Args:
    x (Union[np.ndarray, np.float64]): X-coordinates in Cartesian.
    y (Union[np.ndarray, np.float64]): Y-coordinates in Cartesian.
    z (Union[np.ndarray, np.float64]): Z-coordinates in Cartesian.

    Returns:
    Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]: Tuple of longitude and latitude arrays in radians.
    """
    lon = np.arctan2(y, x)  # Compute longitude using arctan2 for proper handling of quadrant.
    hypot = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)  # Compute the hypotenuse of x and y to use for latitude calculation.
    lat = np.arctan2(z, hypot)  # Compute latitude as the angle from the positive z-axis.
    return lon, lat


@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def cartesian_to_spherical_numba(
    x: Union[np.ndarray, np.float64],
    y: Union[np.ndarray, np.float64],
    z: Union[np.ndarray, np.float64]
    ) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """
    Convert Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates using Numba for JIT compilation to speed up the computation.
    
    Args:
    x (Union[np.ndarray, np.float64]): X-coordinates in Cartesian.
    y (Union[np.ndarray, np.float64]): Y-coordinates in Cartesian.
    z (Union[np.ndarray, np.float64]): Z-coordinates in Cartesian.

    Returns:
    Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]: Tuple of longitude and latitude arrays in radians.
    """
    lon = np.arctan2(y, x)  # Computation of longitude.
    hypot = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)  # Computation of the hypotenuse for latitude calculation.
    lat = np.arctan2(z, hypot)  # Computation of latitude.
    return lon, lat


@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True, cache=True)
def cartesian_to_spherical_numba_parallel(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, z: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """
    Convert Cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates with both parallel processing and JIT compilation
    This version leverages multiple CPU cores to handle large arrays more efficiently.

    Args:
    x (np.ndarray): X-coordinates in Cartesian.
    y (np.ndarray): Y-coordinates in Cartesian.
    z (np.ndarray): Z-coordinates in Cartesian.

    Returns:
    Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]: Tuple of longitude and latitude arrays in radians.
    """
    lon = np.empty_like(x)  # Preallocate the array for longitude.
    lat = np.empty_like(x)  # Preallocate the array for latitude.
    for i in prange(x.size):  # Use parallel range (prange) to distribute loop iterations across multiple threads.
        lon[i] = np.arctan2(y[i], x[i])  # Compute longitude for each element in parallel.
        hypot = np.sqrt(x[i]**2 + y[i]**2)  # Compute the hypotenuse for each element in parallel.
        lat[i] = np.arctan2(z[i], hypot)  # Compute latitude for each element in parallel.
    return lon, lat

Usage
Testing with x, y, and z as np.float64
# Ensure Numba function is compiled before timing - only used for testing - not required when using functions in a loop
_ = cartesian_to_spherical_numba(np.array([1.0]), np.array([1.0]), np.array([1.0]))

# extract x, y, and z values as numpy.float64
x_ecl = ecliptic_coords._sky_coord_frame._data.x.value
y_ecl = ecliptic_coords._sky_coord_frame._data.y.value
z_ecl = ecliptic_coords._sky_coord_frame._data.z.value

# time the non-parallel functions
%timeit cartesian_to_spherical_numpy(x_ecl, y_ecl, z_ecl)
%timeit cartesian_to_spherical_numba(x_ecl, y_ecl, z_ecl)

2.5 µs ± 749 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
267 ns ± 5.27 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

Testing with x, y, and z as np.ndarray
Use if x, y, and z values can be configured into three arrays or coordinates.
# Generate test data
n = 1000000
x = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)
y = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)
z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)

# Ensure Numba function is compiled before timing
_ = cartesian_to_spherical_numba(np.array([1.0]), np.array([1.0]), np.array([1.0]))
_ = cartesian_to_spherical_numba_parallel(np.array([1.0]), np.array([1.0]), np.array([1.0]))

# time all the functions
%timeit cartesian_to_spherical_numpy(x, y, z)
%timeit cartesian_to_spherical_numba(x, y, z)
%timeit cartesian_to_spherical_numba_parallel(x, y, z)

43.3 ms ± 562 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
38 ms ± 302 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
4.99 ms ± 194 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Radians and Degree, Minute, Seconds
.lat and .lon return values formatted as (degrees, minutes, seconds), while the numpy and numba functions return values as radians. The following code presents additional format options, which are not considered in the timing analysis.
Converting Radians to Degrees
@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def cartesian_to_spherical_numba_deg(x, y, z):
    lon = np.arctan2(y, x)
    hypot = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    lat = np.arctan2(z, hypot)
    return np.degrees(lon), np.degrees(lat)  # return results in degrees

Formatting as Degrees, Minutes, and Seconds
# Example radians-to-degree conversion
lon_rad = np.array([2.61799388])  # longitude in radians
lat_rad = np.array([0.33161256])  # latitude in radians

# Convert radians to degrees
lon_deg, lat_deg = np.degrees(lon_rad), np.degrees(lat_rad)

# Create Angle objects and format them
lon_angle = Angle(lon_deg, u.degree)
lat_angle = Angle(lat_deg, u.degree)

# Print formatted angles
print(lon_angle.to_string(unit=u.degree, sep=('d', 'm', 's')))
print(lat_angle.to_string(unit=u.degree, sep=('d', 'm', 's')))

